# Constructing $|K|$ given an abstract simplicial complex $K = (V,\Sigma)$

Tags: algebraic-topology, simplicial-complex

On Pg. $9$ of [these notes](http://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/lackenby/tg050908.pdf), Lackenby introduces *Abstract Simplicial Complexes*. The topological realization of a simplicial complex $K$, denoted $|K|$, is given by the following recipe:

> [image]

The author claims that:

> For each $\sigma\in \Sigma$, there is a homeomorphic copy of $\triangle_\sigma$ in $|K|$. Also, $|K|$ is a disjoint union of the interiors of the simplices.

How do I prove this result? I am struggling to find an **explicit** homeomorphism possibly due to the *not-so-explicit* construction of $|K|$. What even is the topology on $|K|$? It is not clear.

Intuitively, it is immediate from the construction itself that for every $\sigma$ we choose a copy $\triangle_\sigma$. However, the *identification* via face-inclusion does not seem explicit.

---

Please let me know if any notation is not clear, although the attached notes are self-contained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The construction of $\lvert K \rvert$ is in fact somewhat vague. But we can make it precise:

1. If $\sigma \in K$ has $n+1$ elements, we say that *$\sigma$ has dimension $\dim \sigma = n$*.
2. For each $\sigma \in K$ let $\Delta_\sigma = \Delta^{\dim \sigma}$ be the standard simplex having the dimension of $\sigma$. Choose a bijection $b_\sigma : \sigma \to V(\Delta_\sigma)$. This is meant by labelling the vertices with the elements of $\sigma$.
3. Form the disjoint union of standard simplices $\Delta_\sigma$:
   $$D = \bigcup_{\sigma \in K} \Delta_\sigma \times \{\sigma\}$$
4. Define an equivalence relation on $D$ by identifying $\Delta_\sigma$ with a geometric face of $\Delta_\tau$ whenever $\sigma \subset \tau$. More precisely, define a vertex map
   $$f_{\sigma,\tau} : V(\Delta_\sigma) \stackrel{b_\sigma^{-1}}{\to} \sigma \hookrightarrow \tau \stackrel{b_\tau}{\to} V(\Delta_\tau)$$
   and let $\phi_{\sigma,\tau} : \Delta_\sigma \to \Delta_\tau$ denote ist affine extension. This map embeds $\Delta_\sigma$ as a geometric face of $\Delta_\tau$.
   The above equivalence relation $\sim$ identifies each $(x,\sigma) \in D$ with $(\phi_{\sigma,\tau}(x),\tau) \in D$. Note that two distinct points of $\Delta_\sigma \times \{\sigma\}$ are never equivalent.
5. Define $\lvert K \rvert = D/\sim$ and give it the quotient topology induced by the quotient map $p : D \to \lvert K \rvert$.

It is now clear that the map
$$i_\sigma : \Delta_\sigma \to \lvert K \rvert, x \to p(x,\sigma)$$
is a continuous bijection onto its image. It is also easy to see that $i_\sigma$ is a closed map, thus an embedding.

The interior of $\Delta'_\sigma = i_\sigma(\Delta_\sigma)$ is defined as the image under $i_\sigma$ of the interior of $\Delta_\sigma$. Note that this concept is different from the *topological interior* of $\Delta'_\sigma$ in $\lvert K \rvert$; in fact, the topological interior of $\Delta'_\sigma $ is in general not open in $\lvert K \rvert$. So perhaps it would be better to call it the *simplicial interior* of $\Delta'_\sigma$.

Comment: I am not very sure about the relation $\sim$. Are we thinking of the bijection $\phi_{\sigma,\tau} : \triangle_\sigma \to \phi_{\sigma,\tau}(\triangle_\sigma)$, and relating corresponding points? Clearly this is a surjection, and it is an injection because it is a composition of injections.

Comment: @epsilon-emperor You are right, $i_\sigma$ is not surjective. I edited my my answer.

Comment: Why do we need to check that $i_\sigma$ is a closed map? It is clear that $i_\sigma$ is a homeomorphism from whatever we saw before that step. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, we are identifying the points related by the bijection $\phi_{\sigma,\tau}$.

Comment: A continuous bijection is in general not a homeomorphism. This is assured by the fact that $i_\sigma$ is a closed map. Alternatively one could show that $\lvert K \rvert$ is Hausdorff, then we could invoke that the domain is compact.